# Updating ejs template with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, ejs, edamam-api

I am creating a web app that returns recipes when a user searches for a specific ingredient(s). I am using the edamam api and decided to use pagination so that I could load more recipes relative to the users search when the user clicks on the "Load more" button. Note that edamam will return 20 recipes at a time.
This is from edamam's documentation on how their pagination works:

> The way pagination works in recipe search API has changed significantly from version 1. The parameters from and to are no longer supported. Instead, responses will contain a pre-constructed URL for the next request in _links.next.href. If this path is not present, then this was the last page and there are no more results.

I largely got this functionality working however, there is a part of my html that utilizes an ejs if statement that is causing some problems (issue in "loadrecipes.js").

My question is 2 fold:

1. How can I resolve the issues with the if statement?
2. Is there a better way to update ejs when using an AJAX request?

**The code. [Git hub repo is here](https://github.com/vperizes/CookYourKitchen_app/tree/main) for easier viewing**

I have 3 files:

1. index.js - server side code
2. index.ejs - html with ejs templating
3. loadrecipes.js - client side code

**index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import 'dotenv/config';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const API_URL = "https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public";
const myId = process.env.ID;
const myAPIKey = process.env.API_KEY;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

let nextPageUrl = null;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs");
})

app.post("/search", async (req, res) => {
    const inputText = req.body.ingrediants;
    try{
        const requestUrl = nextPageUrl || API_URL;

        const response = await axios.get(requestUrl, {
            params: {
                q: inputText,
                app_id: myId,
                app_key: myAPIKey
            }
        });
        const result = response.data;

        //store next page url for pagination
        if(result._links.next.href){
            nextPageUrl = result._links.next.href;
        } else{
            nextPageUrl = null; //no more pages/recipes given the user search
        }

        res.render("index.ejs", {
            recipes: result,
            userInput: inputText,
            nextPageUrl: nextPageUrl
        });
    }catch(error){
        res.render("index.ejs", {
            content: "Looks like there's an issue: " + error.message
        });

    }
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}.`);
})
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cook Your Kitchen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="px-4 py-5 my-4 text-center">
            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-body-emphasis">Cook Your Kitchen</h1>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                <p class="lead mb-4">Have some random ingrediants in your kitchen? <br>
                    Those veggies about to go bad?? <br>
                    Enter the ingrediants you want to use and get recipe suggestions!
                </p>
                <form action="/search" method="post">
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">
                        <input type="text" id="search" name="ingrediants" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Chicken, beans, tomato,..." aria-label="Recipient's username"
                            aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" value="Submit" id="button-addon2">Get a recipe</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <% if(locals.recipes){ %>
        <div class="container px-4 py-5" id="custom-cards">
            <h2>You searched for: <%= userInput %>
            </h2>
            <div id="recipe-list" class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-3 align-items-stretch g-4 py-5">
                <% recipes.hits.forEach(recipe=> { %>
                    <div class="col" onclick="location.href='<%= recipe.recipe.url %>';">
                        <div class="card card-cover h-100 overflow-hidden text-bg-dark rounded-4"
                            style="background-image: url('<%= recipe.recipe.image %>');">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 p-5 pb-3 text-white text-shadow-1 text-bg">
                                <h3 class="mt-5 mb-4 display-6 lh-1 fw-bold">
                                    <%= recipe.recipe.label %>
                                </h3>
                                <ul class="d-flex list-unstyled mt-auto">
                                    <% if (recipe.recipe.dietLabels.length > 0) { %>
                                        <li class="badge text-bg-dark rounded-pill px-2">
                                            <small>
                                                <%= recipe.recipe.dietLabels[0]%>
                                            </small>
                                        </li>
                                        <%} %>

                                            <li class="badge text-bg-dark rounded-pill mx-2 px-2">
                                                <small>
                                                    <%= recipe.recipe.healthLabels[0] %>
                                                </small>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="badge text-bg-dark rounded-pill px-2">
                                                <small>
                                                    <%= recipe.recipe.healthLabels[1] %>
                                                </small>
                                            </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <% })} %>
            </div>
        </div>

      <% if (locals.nextPageUrl){ %>
        <div class="text-center mb-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="loadMoreButton" data-next-page="<%= nextPageUrl %>">Load More</button>
        </div>
      <% } %>
        
      
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" 
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="loadrecipes.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the part in index.ejs I am trying to update (red box)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYWCF.jpg)

**loadrecipes.js**

```
const nextPageUrl = $("#loadMoreButton").data("next-page");

$("#loadMoreButton").on("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation(); 

//using ajax to load more recipes
    if (nextPageUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: nextPageUrl,
            success: (result) => {
                // Append result to the existing recipes
                // and update the nextPageUrl data attribute if there's a next page.
                const moreRecipes = result.hits;
                if(moreRecipes.length > 0){
                    moreRecipes.forEach((recipe) => {
                        //copying card html/ejs from index.ejs and replacing ejs tags for each additionally retrieved recipe
                        const recipeCard = `
                        <div class="col" onclick="location.href='${recipe.recipe.url}';">
                        <div class="card card-cover h-100 overflow-hidden text-bg-dark rounded-4"
                            style="background-image: url('${recipe.recipe.image}');">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 p-5 pb-3 text-white text-shadow-1 text-bg">
                                <h3 class="mt-5 mb-4 display-6 lh-1 fw-bold">
                                    ${recipe.recipe.label}
                                </h3>
                                <ul class="d-flex list-unstyled mt-auto">
                                    <% if (${recipe.recipe.dietLabels.length} > 0) { %>
                                        <li class="badge text-bg-dark rounded-pill px-2">
                                            <small>
                                                ${recipe.recipe.dietLabels[0]}
                                            </small>
                                        </li>
                                        <%} %>

                                            <li class="badge text-bg-dark rounded-pill mx-2 px-2">
                                                <small>
                                                    ${recipe.recipe.healthLabels[0]}
                                                </small>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="badge text-bg-dark rounded-pill px-2">
                                                <small>
                                                    ${recipe.recipe.healthLabels[0]}
                                                </small>
                                            </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        `;

                         // Append the new recipe card to the recipe list div
                         $("#recipe-list").append(recipeCard);
                    });

                        // Update the nextPageUrl data attribute
                        $("#loadMoreButton").data("next-page", result._links.next.href);
                    } else {
                        // If there are no more recipes, hide the "Load More" button
                        $("#loadMoreButton").hide();
                    }
                }
        });
    }
})
```

I've been looking through documentation and other similar questions posted on stack overflow but haven't found much that is helpful to this exact issue. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot trial and error and reading various pieces of documentation I solved my problem by creating a global variable to hold the diet label html/ejs that needed to be updated + appended. I pulling out the if statement in recipeCard variable in loadrecipes.js. and assigned the argument of the if statement to diet label variable. I then referenced the diet label variable in the recipe card update. I am convinced there is likley a better solution but this what I've come up that works.

```
const nextPageUrl = $("#loadMoreButton").data("next-page");

$("#loadMoreButton").on("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation(); 

    let dietLabel = "";

//using ajax to load more recipes
    if (nextPageUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: nextPageUrl,
            success: (result) => {
                // Append result to the existing recipes
                // and update the nextPageUrl data attribute if there's a next page.
                const moreRecipes = result.hits;
                if(moreRecipes.length > 0){
                    moreRecipes.forEach((recipe) => {
                        if(recipe.recipe.dietLabels.length > 0){
                            dietLabel = `
                            <li class="badge text-bg-dark rounded-pill px-2">
                                            <small>
                                                ${recipe.recipe.dietLabels[0]}
                                            </small>
                                        </li>
                            `;
                        }
                        //copying card html/ejs from index.ejs and replacing ejs tags for each additionally retrieved recipe
                        const recipeCard = `
                        <div class="col" onclick="location.href='${recipe.recipe.url}';">
                        <div class="card card-cover h-100 overflow-hidden text-bg-dark rounded-4"
                            style="background-image: url('${recipe.recipe.image}');">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 p-5 pb-3 text-white text-shadow-1 text-bg">
                                <h3 class="mt-5 mb-4 display-6 lh-1 fw-bold">
                                    ${recipe.recipe.label}
                                </h3>
                                <ul class="d-flex list-unstyled mt-auto">
                                             ${dietLabel}
                                            <li class="badge text-bg-dark rounded-pill mx-2 px-2">
                                                <small>
                                                    ${recipe.recipe.healthLabels[0]}
                                                </small>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="badge text-bg-dark rounded-pill px-2">
                                                <small>
                                                    ${recipe.recipe.healthLabels[1]}
                                                </small>
                                            </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        `;

                         // Append the new recipe card to the recipe list div
                         $("#recipe-list").append(recipeCard);
                    });

                        // Update the nextPageUrl data attribute
                        $("#loadMoreButton").data("next-page", result._links.next.href);
                    } else {
                        // If there are no more recipes, hide the "Load More" button
                        $("#loadMoreButton").hide();
                    }
                }
        });
    }
})
```